# Can I create an xml file with one view without the containing layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view called CustomImageView.

I would like to create an xml file with this view so I inflate the view and add it programmatically to my current layout. (depending on orientation , I will decide where to add it)

Is it possible to so something like this in the xml without a containing layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:level="2"
    android:anotherattr="adsad" />
```

After that I will inflate it. or should I put it in a Layout like LinearLayout? I just want an xml with my view so I can inflate it and add to my existing layout.. I am not sure what the containing layout would be!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly legitimate. You can do it with built-in or custom views. [Here is an example from the Android framework](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4e8328c972f136dc1181b5f7c2ce2e335ca9521b/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml). It's an XML layout file containing a single `TextView`, representing a default `ListView` row layout. The `TextView` has several attributes assigned to it in XML, just as your custom view will.

Comment: Asswers the question perfectly

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to so something like this in the xml

Yes you can inflate an XML that just contains one view. But why not just create the view programmatically? `new CustomImageView(...)`

> depending on orientation , I will decide where to add it

Consider using the layout directories such as "layout-land" to automatically inflate different layouts based on orientation - that's what those are for. Read more about this [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

> I am not sure what the containing layout would be

Use the layout directories and it removes all doubt

Comment: Great suggestion (+1 for that). However, Most of the layout is the same except for this specific view. I don't want to copy paste the full layout in two different directories just to support one different view unless there is a different way

Comment: Consider using @include to include only the layout parts that are different